# Get number of not-null fields in Java String array

Tags: java, arrays

I created a String array with 100 fields.

Then, I read in values from a file.

There were only 7 values, but this number could vary anywhere from 1 to 100 so I left the String array with 100 fields.

Essentially, I have a key value that I will use to identify other values that are equal.

However, when I try to check the array for values equal to the key value, I receive a null pointer exception:

```
for(i = 0; i <= memberType.length; i++)
{
    if(memberType[i].equalsIgnoreCase(memberTypeInput))
    {
        out.println(memberCode[i] + " " + memberType[i] + " " + firstName[i] + " " +
                lastName[i] + " " + age[i] + " " + gender[i]);
    }// END IF
}// END FOR
```

From reading several other similar (but not the same) questions/answers, and Googling this problem for a few hours, I now understand that the null pointer exception occurs because I am trying to check my key value against some values which are null.

My question is: what is the best way to avoid the null pointer exception in this case?

More specifically: how do I get Java to find the number of not-null fields?
I think if I can find the number of not-null fields, I can get Java to check my key value against only not-null fields, thus avoiding the null pointer exception.

I tried finding the number of not-null fields with:

```
int index = -1;
for (i = 0; i < memberType.length; i++)
                {
                    if (!memberType[i].equals(null))
                    {
                        index = i;
                    }
                }
```

And then I used "index" in the for loop to search the array for values equal to the key value.

However, the above code throws me another null pointer exception.

In case you want to check it out, all of my code is below. There is some other stuff going on, but I wanted to leave it in so you could get the whole picture. The null pointer exception points to line 157. It's an IF statement.

```
package Phase2;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import static java.lang.System.out;

public class Phase2
{

// DEFINING ARRAYS & VARIABLES //



/////////////////
// MAIN METHOD //
/////////////////
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    int menuSelection;

    start_program();

    menuSelection = Menu();

    switch(menuSelection)
    {
        case 1:
            Modify_member();
            break;

        case 2:
            Modify_registration();
            break;

        case 3:
            Report();
            break;

        case 4:
            end_program();
            System.exit(0);

    }// END SWITCH CASE STATEMENT

}// END MAIN METHOD


////////////////////////////////////////////
// METHOD to run once at start of program //
////////////////////////////////////////////
public static void start_program()
{

    //VARS & ARRAYS FOR start_program() METHOD
    String newLine;

    int count = -1;
    int[] memberCode = new int[100];
    String[] memberType = new String[100];
    String[] firstName = new String[100];
    String[] lastName = new String[100];
    int[] age = new int[100];
    char[] gender = new char[100];

    int menuSelection = 0;
    String menuOutput;
    int i;

    String memberTypeInput;

    try
    {
        BufferedReader membersFile = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("members.dat"));

        while ((newLine = membersFile.readLine()) != null)
            {
                StringTokenizer delimiter = new StringTokenizer(newLine, "#");
                count = count+1;
                memberCode[count] = Integer.parseInt(delimiter.nextToken());
                memberType[count] = delimiter.nextToken();
                firstName[count] = delimiter.nextToken();
                lastName[count] = delimiter.nextToken();
                age[count] = Integer.parseInt(delimiter.nextToken());
                gender[count] = delimiter.nextToken().charAt(0);

            }// END WHILE

        membersFile.close();
    }// END TRY

    catch(IOException error)
    {
        out.println("There was an error on file read " + error);
    }// END CATCH


    //////////
    // MENU //
    //////////
    menuOutput =    "\tMoon Area YMCA" + "\n" +
                    "1. All Member Info" + "\n" +
                    "2. All Members of a Specific Type" + "\n" +
                    "3. All Members Between a Specific Age Range" + "\n" +
                    "4. All Members of a Specific Gender" + "\n" +
                    "5. Report 5" + "\n" +
                    "6. Report 6" + "\n" +
                    "7. Report 7" + "\n" +
                    "8. Report 8" + "\n" +
                    "9. Report 9" + "\n" +
                    "10. Exit Report Menu" + "\n\n" +
                    "Please Make Your Selection";

    while(menuSelection != 10)
    {
        menuSelection = Integer.parseInt
                (JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, menuOutput, "Main Menu", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE));

        switch(menuSelection)
        {
        case 1:
            for (i=0; i<=count; ++i)
            {
                out.println(memberCode[i] + " " + memberType[i] + " " + firstName[i] + " " +
                lastName[i] + " " + age[i] + " " + gender[i]);
            }// END FOR
            break;

        case 2:
            memberTypeInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog
                (null, "Please enter member type", "Info by Member Type", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

            if (memberTypeInput.equalsIgnoreCase("single") ||
                memberTypeInput.equalsIgnoreCase("family") ||
                memberTypeInput.equalsIgnoreCase("couple"))
            {   
                // getting number of non-null fields in memberType array

                //// NEED TO FIND NUMBER OF NOT NULL FIELDS
                /*int index = -1;

                for (i = 0; i < memberType.length; i++)
                {
                    if (!memberType[i].equals(null))
                    {
                        index = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }*/

                // getting index number of each memberTypeInput value in array

                for(i = 0; i <= memberType.length; i++)
                {
                    if(memberType[i].equalsIgnoreCase(memberTypeInput))
                    {
                        out.println(memberCode[i] + " " + memberType[i] + " " + firstName[i] + " " +
                                lastName[i] + " " + age[i] + " " + gender[i]);
                    }// END IF
                }// END FOR

            }// END IF
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog
                    (null, "Please choose 'single', 'couple', or 'family'", "Error", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }// END ELSE
            break;

        case 3:
            break;

        case 4:
            break;

        case 5:
            break;

        case 6:
            break;

        case 7:
            break;

        case 8:
            break;

        case 9:
            break;

        case 10:
            break;

        }// END SWITCH
    }// END WHILE


}// END start_program METHOD


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// METHOD to print menu and return user input selection //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public static int Menu()
{
    String menuSelectionString;
    int menuSelection = 0;
    String output;

    while(menuSelection == 0)
    {
        output =    "Moon Area YMCA\n\n" +
                    "1. Add/Modify Member Information\n" +
                    "2. Add/Modify Class Registrations\n" +
                    "3. Report Section\n" +
                    "4. Exit the System\n\n" +
                    "Please make your selection:" ;

        menuSelectionString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, output, "Main Menu", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
        if (menuSelectionString.equals("1") ||
            menuSelectionString.equals("2") ||
            menuSelectionString.equals("3") ||
            menuSelectionString.equals("4"))
        {
            menuSelection = Integer.parseInt(menuSelectionString);
        }// END IF STATEMENT
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please select a number between 1 and 4.", "Error", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            menuSelection = 0;
        }// END ELSE STATEMENT

    }// END WHILE LOOP

    return menuSelection;

}// END Menu METHOD


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// METHOD to add, delete, change basic member information //
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public static void Modify_member()
{
    out.println("Modify_member() method has executed.");
}// END Modify_member METHOD


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// METHOD to add, delete, change class registration information //
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
public static void Modify_registration()
{
    out.println("Modify_registration() method has executed.");
}// END Modify_registration METHOD


/////////////////////////////
// METHOD to print reports //
/////////////////////////////
public static void Report()
{
    out.println("Report() method has executed.");
}// END Report METHOD


//////////////////////////////////////////
// METHOD to run once at end of program //
//////////////////////////////////////////
public static void end_program()
{
    out.println("end_program() method has executed.");
}// END end_program METHOD

}// END Phase2 CLASS
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why not use array list?

Comment: null does not have a method `.equals` ;) However, you can do `memberType[i] != null`

Comment: P.S. the line where you do `memberType[i] + " " + firstName[i] + " " + lastName[i] + " " + age[i] + " " + gender[i]` is not OO at all... you could easily simplify that all by creating a `Member` object for instance

Comment: @Maxqueue using array list is out of question as this is a specific homework assignment.

Comment: @austinwernli thank you! I assumed I couldn't do != null since it was a String array. I'm a noob :)

Comment: @austinwernli I would majorly appreciate if you elaborated on making a member Object in order to simplify that line as I am a noob. If not, I appreciate the input anyway and I will certainly look into it!

Comment: @JoeKreydt you could have a `Member` object that has the fields `memberType, firstName, lastName, age, gender` then you could just iterate through a list of `members`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't call methods on something that is null; if methodType[i] contains a null reference, then trying to call a method on it results in a NullPointerException. Check that it's null first, using `!=`:

```
if (memberType[i] != null && memberType[i].equals("whatever")) {
    ...
```

This will short-circuit in the event that memberType is null, so that the rest of the expression (after &&) won't be evaluated.

Comment: Oh my gosh, you rock! I hope I have your Java wisdom someday. This worked like a charm. Thank you, thank you, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're getting a null pointer exception because you're trying to compare something that doesn't exist.  What I would recommend is to use Lists instead of arrays.  That way you can dynamically add items to them and never have any need to check for null values.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback! Unfortunately, this is for a Java class, and we are required to use arrays. Thank you for the input though. I was unaware that lists could have items added dynamically.